# curl returns 200 for page not found

Tags: php, curl, error-handling

```
$ch = curl_init();    
$varpost = '&res=1';  // Initiate cURL
$url = 'http://www.testxcvt.com/';// is 404 page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $varpost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // Execute
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
curl_close ($ch); // Close cURL handle
```

PFA the code that i have. i get 200 when i display $code. in my browser i get an advertisement for 404 pages. i am not sure what is the reson to get 200 for 404 page.

Please help

Comment: Is http://www.testxcvt.com/ actual page that you try to get? Because I don't see any 404 page there. That page doesn't exist or it is not active yet.

Comment: no its a randon address i tried which gives me 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try this code below you will see that curl makes post to google and google responds with 405 error so 404 check is false. Then page output is checked for 403 in it and handled.

In your case page doesn't return 405 http code but 200 so you should check page output and set correct error message to find.
Only problem is if that error message occurs somewhere on pages you actually need, then you won't get them also.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();    
$varpost = '&res=1';  // Initiate cURL
$url = 'http://www.google.com/';// is 404 page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $varpost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // Execute
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($code == 404){
    /* handle real 404 here. */
    echo 'real 404 found';
}else{
    // here you can set your own error, for example 'Page Not Found (12)'
    if (strpos($output, '405') !== false) {
        // 404 page found
        echo 'Google custom error 405 found';
        print_r($output);
    }else{
        // no 404 error
        echo 'Google custom error not found';
        print_r($output);
    }
}
curl_close ($ch); // Close cURL handle 
?>
```

Comment: yes... but i need to handle 404 pages in my code. in teh source code of 404 page i see page not found as below :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<title>Page Not Found (12)</title>
</head>
<body id='mainBody'>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://midascdn.nervesis.com/spring/js/nxd.js?oyenl%60ho=vvv%2fudruybwu%2fbn&nshfho=vvv%2fudruybwu%2fbn&sdgdsds='></script>

Comment: ok I didn't understand you.. see updated code.. is that what you need?

Comment: I think I get it now. Curl returns 200 because page is actually found but on that page you have 404 info. So, as I see it, you should do error handling by checking `$output`.

Comment: you should check if 404 error message exist on that page.. example is added in my code

Comment: i added this piece of code 
  if($code == 404){
  /* Handle 404 here. */
  }else if (strpos($output, 'Page Not Found')) {
   // 404 found
   echo 'page not found';
  }
atleast now i am able to detect if it returns page not found. thanks guys

Comment: if 'Page Not Found' content exists on that 404 page then it should work... if not then try code with google that I set so you can see how it works

Comment: @Ps-kl and please mark answers as useful and accept answer if it helped or solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you executing the code from?

When I try it locally, I get:

```
error:Could not resolve host: www.testxcvt.com
```

And `$code` comes back as `0`.

If you try another URL, like `http://www.text.com` - does it work?

Comment: i hv this in a php file. however www.text.com is a valid sit :)

Comment: basically for both valid and 404 site address i am getting 200 as the result

Comment: Could you perhaps try with [Guzzle](https://guzzle.readthedocs.org/) and see what status code you get?